# Index is not used if the Query is executed after another one

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I am testing the benefits of clustered and unclustered indexes for a training purpose

I noted from the execution plan that if a query is executed after another one, the index (clustered or unclustered) is not used.

If I put a 'GO' before the second query, then the index is used.

Can anyone explain to me the reason?

Below the complete scripts

```
create table tab_string_ind(id int identity(1,1), string varchar(10) primary key(string)) 
create table tab_string(id int identity(1,1), string varchar(10));
create table tab_string_uncl(id int identity(1,1), string varchar(10));
create NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_tabstrin ON tab_string_uncl(string);
go;

with cte as(
select 97 n , char(97) s
union all
select 1+n, char(1+n) from cte
where n < 122)
insert into tab_string
select t1.s+t2.s+t3.s+t4.s+t5.s from cte t1 
inner join cte t2 on 1=1
inner join cte t3 on 1=1
inner join cte t4 on 1=1
inner join cte t5 on 1=1
go

insert into tab_string_ind(string) select string from tab_string
insert into tab_string_uncl(string) select string from tab_string
```

Scripts tested with execution Plan

```
select id,string from tab_string_uncl where string  = 'abcdg';
select id,string from tab_string_ind where string  = 'abcdg';
select id,string from tab_string where string  = 'abcdg';
```

[image]

If I run each script separately the index if exists, is used

Comment: Query2 from the estimated plan is not the 2nd query from your list, but the 3rd one - it shows you exactly what query2 is for it in the details and it's right, you don't have an index on the tab_string table.

Comment: On the contrary, the screenshot shows that the only index, the one on `tab_string_uncl ` is used. The other tables have no indexes on `string`.

Comment: The screenshot also shows that the unindexed `tab_string` table was queried twice. That execution plan doesn't match the question's queries

Comment: Yes, I see now the reason, the execution plan is showing query3 tow times